# Flutter: how to create post request with form data same js code

Tags: flutter

I want to upload an image to the server with flutter, in js t use form data with input file but with flutter I don't know what to do.

in js:

```
formData.append("file", e.clipboardData.files[0]);
                    formData.append("session", sessionid);
                    formData.append("fileindex", fileListIndex);

var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var protocol = window.location.protocol;

    if (hostname === "localhost") {
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:9999/" + uploadpoint, true);
    } else if (hostname === "www.aladin.finance") {
        xhr.open("POST", protocol + "//uploadfile.aladin.finance" + "/"
                + uploadpoint, true);
    } else {
        xhr.open("POST", protocol + "//uploadfile." + hostname + "/"
                + uploadpoint, true);
    }

    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter has this great package called Dio to handle all sort of http requests. It's very easy to do what you want with it. Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata

Comment: Thank you, but my server is protected by cloud flare or token with header, so dio not work.

Comment: in browser: general
Request URL: https://uploadfile.aladin.finance/uploadfile
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.26.9.119:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: request header:
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJHyLqJD0hZBHQQMx
Origin: https://www.aladin.finance
Referer: https://www.aladin.finance/private/investordashboard
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36

Comment: form data:
file: (binary)
session: 1548859027342087_0.36074956226047605
fileindex: 0